# How can I convert my input statement to json to pass it as the output parameter?

Tags: elasticsearch, output, logstash

I am using logstash with output jdbc to send the data to postgresql, the problem is that since there are many values I do not know in which cast it fails, so I would like to send all the input parameters as a single json string.
Can you do something like that? from the input base I can't do this.

```
    input {
  jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/ifxjdbc-4.50.3.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:informix-sqli://xxxxxxxx"
        jdbc_user => "***"
        jdbc_password => "****"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM informix.test WHERE id_nvd_com > :sql_last_value"
        use_column_value => true
        tracking_column => id_nvd_com
        last_run_metadata_path => "/var/log/logstash/value/test_last_value.yml"
        tags => "test"
  }
}

output {
  if "test" in [tags] {
        stdout { codec => json_lines }
        jdbc {
                connection_string => 'jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxxxx'
                statement => ["SELECT * FROM public.sp_lgs_test(?, ?, ?)", "test1", "test2", "test3"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [`json_encode`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json_encode.html) filter?

Comment: @Val, I read it, but I would not know how to do it with my statement